# How to fill color in an image

Tags: flutter

i use ColorFilter with BlendMo[enter image description here][3]de.srcOut,the problem is how to remove red color？
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPDto.png)
[the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ngvb.png)

Comment: please inline the code (as in text) and the image. Furthermore explain what better what you tried and what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

```
ColorFilter.mode(Colors.transparent);
//currently it is Colors.red
```